# Style MaterialDialog not being applied

Tags: android, dialog, styles

I am trying to set a **custom style** to a (material) dialog but it is not being applied, it just shows the default (white) one.

I already checked some sources and googled around but somehow I am not getting the result I want.

Please be aware that I am new to styling. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you.

**MyAlertDialogStyle:**

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <!-- Used for the buttons -->
   <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
   <!-- Used for the title and text -->
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
   <!-- Used for the background -->
   <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>
</style>
```

**Utils.class** where the dialog is being created:

```
public static MaterialDialog createDarkLoadingDialog(Activity activity, int myAlertDialogStyle) {
        return new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
                .title(R.string.loading)
                .content(R.string.wait)
                .progress(true, 0)
                .cancelable(false)
                .build();
    }
```

The **Activity** where I show the dialog:

```
public class ConversationDetailActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<BaseResponse> {

MaterialDialog pd;
..
pd = Utils.createDarkLoadingDialog(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
pd.show();
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem, I solved it by using a contextwrapper.

```
public static MaterialDialog createDarkLoadingDialog(Activity activity) {
        ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        return new MaterialDialog.Builder(ctw)
                .title(R.string.loading)
                .content(R.string.wait)
                .progress(true, 0)
                .cancelable(false)
                .build();
    }
```

Then just call/show the dialog in your activity:

```
pd = Utils.createDarkLoadingDialog(this);
pd.show();
```